# Bayesian network on non-normal data

Tags: bayesian-network

I have a dataset of continuous non-normal data (values are scores from 0 to ~1.9), I'm reading the `bnlearn` to see how analyzed this data but I'm not sure how to deal as the data follows a non-normal pattern.

I'm thinking about about discretizing data in three categories (low score, intermediate score, high score), for some variables I cannot discretize in 3, just 2.

Is this a good way to deal with non-normal data? Or is there a better way to deal with this?

Thanks.

Comment: First thing, if you discretize it, it will still be non-normal. So that helps you none. What is the actual distribution of the raw values? Is there a suitable transformation?

Comment: Yes, I know, but if I discretize the values I'm no longer using the same algorithm for the networks structure discovery, thats my question. 
The distribution looks like an exponential distribution when I plot it with all values between 0 and ~1.9 for ~1000 samples and 67 variables.

Comment: Have you overlooked the log transformation as a possibility here?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't into a normal distribution.

Comment: Bayes nets need exact probability models. What about an SEM instead with a robust variance estimator?

Comment: Something as the Mean + SEM? I'll think/read about this. It might be a solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75225/discussion-between-adamo-and-biorunner88).